# Converting A String To Hexadecimal In Java

Tags: java, string, hex

I am trying to convert a string like "testing123" into hexadecimal form in java. I am currently using BlueJ.

And to convert it back, is it the same thing except backward?

Answer (score 227):

Here's a short way to convert it to hex:

```
public String toHex(String arg) {
    return String.format("%040x", new BigInteger(1, arg.getBytes(/*YOUR_CHARSET?*/)));
}
```

Comment: +1 to the most pure sample of 3vilness I ever saw: using a BigInteger to convert from a byte[]...

Comment: Love it! No loops and no bit-flipping. I want to give you 0xFF upvotes :)

Comment: to ensure 40 Characters, you should add zero padding:

return String.format("%040x", new BigInteger(arg.getBytes(/*YOUR_CHARSET?*/)));

Comment: what about converting negative values which use 8 Characters and want them to fit in only 4?

Comment: @Kaleb Have you idea if possible to convert resulted String back? If, yes, can you give me some hints? Thanks!

Comment: Just add if(arg.equals("")){return ""} before the return line.

Comment: You have to use the `BigInteger(int,byte[])` constructor; otherwise if the first byte is negative you get a negative BigInteger.

Comment: I had a `byte[] bytes` as input, and landed on this answer. This is what you need in this case: `return bytes.length == 0 ? "" : String.format("%0" + (bytes.length * 2) + "x", new BigInteger(1, bytes));`

Comment: How to do the reverse - hex to String?

Comment: Please don't use this "solution", it's by far the slowest way to do this kind of conversion.

Comment: It can lose the first `0`, for example for SHA512(SHA512("hello")) it starts with `592a` while should start with `0592`.

Answer (score 69):

To ensure that the hex is always 40 characters long, the BigInteger has to be positive:

```
public String toHex(String arg) {
  return String.format("%x", new BigInteger(1, arg.getBytes(/*YOUR_CHARSET?*/)));
}
```

Comment: This method is actually the correct one. Try `byte[] data = { -1, 1 };` -- code in this answer works fine, whereas that with 17 upvotes fails.

Comment: Is it possible to get a byte with value `-1` out of a string (as was requested in the example)?

Comment: @KalebPederson [Yes. It's not even very hard.](https://www.ideone.com/SXaeVY). If your chosen encoding _ever_ uses the most significant bit of any character (say, like UTF-\* do), you have negative `byte`s in your array.

Answer (score 57):

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex;
...

String hexString = Hex.encodeHexString(myString.getBytes(/* charset */));
```

http://commons.apache.org/codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Hex.html

Comment: Interesting, if you don't want to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @MelNicholson there's a decodeHex function in Hex to go to a byte[]. You need to use that because nothing guarantees that a random HEX string can be converted to a string in your encoding.

Answer (score 22):

Use [`DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter.html#printHexBinary(byte[])):

```
public static String toHexadecimal(String text) throws UnsupportedEncodingException
{
    byte[] myBytes = text.getBytes("UTF-8");

    return DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(myBytes);
}
```

Example usage:

```
System.out.println(toHexadecimal("Hello StackOverflow"));
```

Prints:

```
48656C6C6F20537461636B4F766572666C6F77
```

**Note**: This causes a little extra trouble with `Java 9` and newer since the API is not included by default. For reference e.g. see [this](https://github.com/http-kit/http-kit/issues/356) `GitHub` issue.

Answer (score 21):

The numbers that you encode into hexadecimal must represent some encoding of the characters, such as UTF-8. So first convert the String to a byte[] representing the string in that encoding, then convert each byte to hexadecimal.

```
public static String hexadecimal(String input, String charsetName) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    if (input == null) throw new NullPointerException();
    return asHex(input.getBytes(charsetName));
}

private static final char[] HEX_CHARS = "0123456789abcdef".toCharArray();

public static String asHex(byte[] buf)
{
    char[] chars = new char[2 * buf.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < buf.length; ++i)
    {
        chars[2 * i] = HEX_CHARS[(buf[i] & 0xF0) >>> 4];
        chars[2 * i + 1] = HEX_CHARS[buf[i] & 0x0F];
    }
    return new String(chars);
}
```

Comment: This is an interesting solution and one that strikes at the core of digital representation of data. Could you please explain what you are doing though, and what the "magic numbers" in your solution represent? A newcomer may not know what the >>> operator means, why we use the bitwise-and & along with a mask of 0xF0, or why the chars array is of size [2 * buf.length].

Answer (score 16):

**Java 17** introduces a utility class for  hexadecimal formatting: **java.util.HexFormat**

Convert to hex:

```
public String toHex(String value) {
    return HexFormat.of().formatHex(value.getBytes());
}
```

Convert from hex:

```
public String fromHex(String value) {
    return new String(HexFormat.of().parseHex(value));
}
```

More about HexFormat [here](https://www.baeldung.com/java-hexformat)

Documentation: [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/HexFormat.html)

Answer (score 12):

Here an other solution

```
public static String toHexString(byte[] ba) {
    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i = 0; i < ba.length; i++)
        str.append(String.format("%x", ba[i]));
    return str.toString();
}

public static String fromHexString(String hex) {
    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < hex.length(); i+=2) {
        str.append((char) Integer.parseInt(hex.substring(i, i + 2), 16));
    }
    return str.toString();
}
```

Comment: Nice but I would use `format("%02x")` so format() always uses 2 chars.  Even though ASCII is double digit hex  ie A=0x65

Answer (score 9):

All answers based on String.getBytes() involve **encoding** your string according to a Charset. You don't necessarily get the hex value of the 2-byte **characters** that make up your string. If what you actually want is the equivalent of a hex viewer, then you need to access the chars directly. Here's the function that I use in my code for debugging Unicode issues:

```
static String stringToHex(String string) {
  StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder(200);
  for (char ch: string.toCharArray()) {
    if (buf.length() > 0)
      buf.append(' ');
    buf.append(String.format("%04x", (int) ch));
  }
  return buf.toString();
}
```

Then, stringToHex("testing123") will give you:

```
0074 0065 0073 0074 0069 006e 0067 0031 0032 0033
```

Comment: This is fine if what you want is to see the internal representation of the Java characters, which is UTF-16, a specific representation of Unicode.

Comment: This prints leading zeroes even if they are not actually in memory. Java does [not](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/254) always use UTF-16 anymore.

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest something like this, where `str` is your input string:

```
StringBuffer hex = new StringBuffer();
char[] raw = tokens[0].toCharArray();
for (int i=0;i<raw.length;i++) {
    if     (raw[i]<=0x000F) { hex.append("000"); }
    else if(raw[i]<=0x00FF) { hex.append("00" ); }
    else if(raw[i]<=0x0FFF) { hex.append("0"  ); }
    hex.append(Integer.toHexString(raw[i]).toUpperCase());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the correction, Software Monkey. I was pretty tired when I wrote the answer, and my test for 'raw[i] <= 9' is clearly insufficient.

Comment: This works really good, is there a way to reverse the generated hex back to string again?

Comment: Where is str in this ?

Answer (score 5):

```
byte[] bytes = string.getBytes(CHARSET); // you didn't say what charset you wanted
BigInteger bigInt = new BigInteger(bytes);
String hexString = bigInt.toString(16); // 16 is the radix
```

You could return `hexString` at this point, with the caveat that leading null-chars will be stripped, and the result will have an odd length if the first byte is less than 16. If you need to handle those cases, you can add some extra code to pad with 0s:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
while ((sb.length() + hexString.length()) < (2 * bytes.length)) {
  sb.append("0");
}
sb.append(hexString);
return sb.toString();
```

Answer (score 5):

To get the Integer value of hex

```
        //hex like: 0xfff7931e to int
        int hexInt = Long.decode(hexString).intValue();
```

Answer (score 4):

Convert a letter in hex code and hex code in letter.

```
        String letter = "a";
    String code;
    int decimal;

    code = Integer.toHexString(letter.charAt(0));
    decimal = Integer.parseInt(code, 16);

    System.out.println("Hex code to " + letter + " = " + code);
    System.out.println("Char to " + code + " = " + (char) decimal);
```

Answer (score 4):

One line HEX encoding/decoding without external libs (Java 8 and above):

Encoding :

```
String hexString = inputString.chars().mapToObj(c -> 
Integer.toHexString(c)).collect(Collectors.joining());
```

Decoding :

```
String decodedString = Stream.iterate(0, i -> i+2)
                .limit(hexString.length()/2 + Math.min(hexString.length()%2,1))
                .map(i -> "" + (char)Integer.parseInt("" + hexString.charAt(i) + hexString.charAt(i+1),16))
                .collect(Collectors.joining());
```

Answer (score 3):

To go the other way (hex to string), you can use

```
public String hexToString(String hex) {
    return new String(new BigInteger(hex, 16).toByteArray());
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Using Multiple Peoples help from multiple Threads..

I know this has been answered, but i would like to give a full encode & decode method for any others in my same situation..

Here's my Encoding & Decoding methods..

```
// Global Charset Encoding
public static Charset encodingType = StandardCharsets.UTF_8;

// Text To Hex
public static String textToHex(String text)
{
    byte[] buf = null;
    buf = text.getBytes(encodingType);
    char[] HEX_CHARS = "0123456789abcdef".toCharArray();
    char[] chars = new char[2 * buf.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < buf.length; ++i)
    {
        chars[2 * i] = HEX_CHARS[(buf[i] & 0xF0) >>> 4];
        chars[2 * i + 1] = HEX_CHARS[buf[i] & 0x0F];
    }
    return new String(chars);
}

// Hex To Text
public static String hexToText(String hex)
{
    int l = hex.length();
    byte[] data = new byte[l / 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < l; i += 2)
    {
        data[i / 2] = (byte) ((Character.digit(hex.charAt(i), 16) << 4)
            + Character.digit(hex.charAt(i + 1), 16));
    }
    String st = new String(data, encodingType);
    return st;
}
```

Comment: Nice! Only on line 13, ">>>" should be ">>"

Answer (score 2):

First convert it into bytes using getBytes() function and then convert it into hex usign this :

```
private static String hex(byte[] bytes) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i=0; i<bytes.length; i++) {
        sb.append(String.format("%02X ",bytes[i]));
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Much better:

```
public static String fromHexString(String hex, String sourceEncoding ) throws  IOException{
    ByteArrayOutputStream bout = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    byte[] buffer = new byte[512];
    int _start=0;
    for (int i = 0; i < hex.length(); i+=2) {
        buffer[_start++] = (byte)Integer.parseInt(hex.substring(i, i + 2), 16);
        if (_start >=buffer.length || i+2>=hex.length()) {
            bout.write(buffer);
            Arrays.fill(buffer, 0, buffer.length, (byte)0);
            _start  = 0;
        }
    }

    return  new String(bout.toByteArray(), sourceEncoding);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Exer5{

    public String ConvertToHexadecimal(int num){
        int r;
        String bin="\0";

        do{
            r=num%16;
            num=num/16;

            if(r==10)
            bin="A"+bin;

            else if(r==11)
            bin="B"+bin;

            else if(r==12)
            bin="C"+bin;

            else if(r==13)
            bin="D"+bin;

            else if(r==14)
            bin="E"+bin;

            else if(r==15)
            bin="F"+bin;

            else
            bin=r+bin;
        }while(num!=0);

        return bin;
    }

    public int ConvertFromHexadecimalToDecimal(String num){
        int a;
        int ctr=0;
        double prod=0;

        for(int i=num.length(); i>0; i--){

            if(num.charAt(i-1)=='a'||num.charAt(i-1)=='A')
            a=10;

            else if(num.charAt(i-1)=='b'||num.charAt(i-1)=='B')
            a=11;

            else if(num.charAt(i-1)=='c'||num.charAt(i-1)=='C')
            a=12;

            else if(num.charAt(i-1)=='d'||num.charAt(i-1)=='D')
            a=13;

            else if(num.charAt(i-1)=='e'||num.charAt(i-1)=='E')
            a=14;

            else if(num.charAt(i-1)=='f'||num.charAt(i-1)=='F')
            a=15;

            else
            a=Character.getNumericValue(num.charAt(i-1));
            prod=prod+(a*Math.pow(16, ctr));
            ctr++;
        }
        return (int)prod;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){

        Exer5 dh=new Exer5();
        Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);

        int num;
        String numS;
        int choice;

        System.out.println("Enter your desired choice:");
        System.out.println("1 - DECIMAL TO HEXADECIMAL             ");
        System.out.println("2 - HEXADECIMAL TO DECIMAL              ");
        System.out.println("0 - EXIT                          ");

        do{
            System.out.print("\nEnter Choice: ");
            choice=s.nextInt();

            if(choice==1){
                System.out.println("Enter decimal number: ");
                num=s.nextInt();
                System.out.println(dh.ConvertToHexadecimal(num));
            }

            else if(choice==2){
                System.out.println("Enter hexadecimal number: ");
                numS=s.next();
                System.out.println(dh.ConvertFromHexadecimalToDecimal(numS));
            }
        }while(choice!=0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
new BigInteger(1, myString.getBytes(/*YOUR_CHARSET?*/)).toString(16)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Convert String to Hexadecimal**:

```
public String hexToString(String hex) {
    return Integer.toHexString(Integer.parseInt(hex));
}
```

definitely this is the easy way.

Comment: This is not a solution. The question is asking how to get the hex representation of the content of an arbitrary String, and specifically provided _"testing123"_ as an example.

Answer (score 0):

[Here are some benchmarks](https://github.com/jamespedwards42/jhex#benchmarks) comparing different approaches and libraries.  Guava beats Apache Commons Codec at decoding. Commons Codec beats Guava at encoding. And JHex beats them both for decoding and encoding.

#### JHex example

```
String hexString = "596f752772652077656c636f6d652e";
byte[] decoded = JHex.decodeChecked(hexString);
System.out.println(new String(decoded));
String reEncoded = JHex.encode(decoded);
```

Everything is in a [single class file for JHex](https://github.com/jamespedwards42/jhex/blob/master/src/main/java/com/fabahaba/encode/JHex.java#L7).  Feel free to copy paste if you don't want yet another library in your dependency tree.  Also note, it is only available as Java 9 jar until I can figure out how to publish multiple release targets with Gradle and the Bintray plugin.

Answer (score 0):

check this solution for String to hex and hex to String vise-versa

```
public class TestHexConversion {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try{
        String clearText = "testString For;0181;with.love";
        System.out.println("Clear Text  = " + clearText);
        char[] chars = clearText.toCharArray();
        StringBuffer hex = new StringBuffer();
        for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
            hex.append(Integer.toHexString((int) chars[i]));
        }
        String hexText = hex.toString();
        System.out.println("Hex Text  = " + hexText);
        String decodedText = HexToString(hexText);
        System.out.println("Decoded Text = "+decodedText);
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static String HexToString(String hex){

      StringBuilder finalString = new StringBuilder();
      StringBuilder tempString = new StringBuilder();

      for( int i=0; i<hex.length()-1; i+=2 ){
          String output = hex.substring(i, (i + 2));
          int decimal = Integer.parseInt(output, 16);
          finalString.append((char)decimal);
          tempString.append(decimal);
      }
    return finalString.toString();
}
```

Output as follows :

> Clear Text  = testString For;0181;with.love
>
> Hex Text  = 74657374537472696e6720466f723b303138313b776974682e6c6f7665
>
> Decoded Text = testString For;0181;with.love

Answer (score -1):

A short and convenient way to convert a String to its Hexadecimal notation is:

```
public static void main(String... args){
String str = "Hello! This is test string.";
char ch[] = str.toCharArray();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < ch.length; i++) {
        sb.append(Integer.toHexString((int) ch[i]));
    }
    System.out.println(sb.toString());
}
```