# string to hex value

Tags: java, string

Is there any java utility to convert string to hex value (integer) ?

Comment: Do you want to turn a string such as "abc" into the hex value of each character, or are you trying to turn something like "0x3df" into a numerical value?

Comment: Do you mean a string that represents a number? Or an arbitrary text string?

Comment: Your question is too ambiguous.  Give some examples of your desired input and output.

Comment: Maybe look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/923863/16632604

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When you have a string starting with 0x or #

```
Integer.decode(hexStr);
```

is the goal

Or

```
Integer.parseInt(hexString, 16);
```

Comment: This is what i need, thanx.. Integer i = Integer.decode("0xA"); System.out.println(i); output : 10

Answer (score 4):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
Integer.toHexString(Integer.parseInt(String));
```

Answer (score 3):

Your question is a little ambiguous, I think.

If you have a hex string (e.g. "ab10"), then you can use

```
int i = Integer.valueOf(s, 16).intValue();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try some of the methods of the [Integer](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html) class:

```
Integer.toHexString(Integer.parseInt(myString, 10))
```

This assumes that your original string is an integer base ten.