# Big Integer and Hex Strings in java

Tags: java, hex, biginteger

I am trying to convert a hex string to a decimal value (integer). Having found

```
int i = Integer.valueOf(s, 16).intValue();
```

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1097742/string-to-hex-value),

i achieved to convert a hex string up to a certain size to an int.

But when the string gets larger, then the int or long does not work, so i tried BigInteger.

Unfortunately, it returns an error :

```
JEncrytion.java:186: <identifier> expected
                        BigInteger part_user_hex = Integer.valueOf("45ffaaaaa", 16).int();


JEncrytion.java:186: illegal start of expression
                        BigInteger part_user_hex = Integer.valueOf("45ffaaaaa", 16).int();


JEncrytion.java:186: not a statement
                        BigInteger part_user_hex = Integer.valueOf("45ffaaaaa", 16).int();
```

The code fragment is :

```
String[] parts = final_key.split("@") ;

String part_fixed = parts[0]; 

String part_user = parts[1]; 

BigInteger part_user_hex = Integer.valueOf("45ffaaaaa", 16).int();

System.out.println(""); 

System.out.println("hex value of the key : " + part_user_hex);
```

Any ideas what to do?

3 errors

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java convert a HEX String to a BigInt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4316645/java-convert-a-hex-string-to-a-bigint)

Comment: yes, it was perfect...just looking in another direction/ with other keywords. Thanx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to assign a primitive int value to a BigInteger reference variable. That won't work. You want to do

```
BigInteger hex = new BigInteger("45ffaaaaa", 16);
```

Also, you've named your class *JEncrytion* instead of *JEncryption*.