# java output hex (ByteArrayOutputStream)

Tags: java

I have :

```
ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
encoder.encode(question, outputStream);
```

and when `System.out.println(outputStream)` prints this .. i see `0►☻☺♣▬♂test some` and I want to see this in HEX like `30 04 12 54 33`

How can I do that ?

Thanks

I was able to write the binary to a file like this :

```
File file = new File("out.bin");
FileOutputStream filename = new FileOutputStream(file);
outputStream.writeTo(filename);
```

Comment: look here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/2149927/986169

Comment: for my case is there a solution ? just for this example .. i'm not so good at this so ... :|

Comment: I write the binary to a file like `outputStream.writeTo(filename)` where file is `File file = new File("out.bin"); FileOutputStream filename = new FileOutputStream(file);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although the `System.out.println()` method can print different things out, it is mainly for printing strings. For this purpose, it will try to convert the input into character string according to the platform or some explicitly given character encoding. To print raw bytes as hex, you need some manipulation before printing them out. The following example might be useful to you.

```
import java.io.*;

class PrintHex
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        byte[] raw = {0x30,0x04,0x12,0x54,0x33};
        byte[] raw1 = {'G','I','F'};
        ByteArrayOutputStream bo = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ByteArrayOutputStream bo1 = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bo.write(raw,0,raw.length);
        bo1.write(raw1,0,raw1.length);

        System.out.println(bo);
        System.out.println(bo1);

        System.out.println("0x" + getHex(raw));
        System.out.println("0x" + getHex(raw1));
    }
    static final String HEXES = "0123456789ABCDEF";

    public static String getHex( byte [] raw ) {
        if ( raw == null ) {
           return null;
        }
        final StringBuilder hex = new StringBuilder( 2 * raw.length );
        for ( final byte b : raw ) {
           hex.append(HEXES.charAt((b & 0xF0) >> 4))
         .append(HEXES.charAt((b & 0x0F)));
        }
        return hex.toString();
   }
}
```

The `getHex` method is from http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0596.html

Comment: pufos, what do you mean by binary to hex? ByteArrayOutputStream to hex? Change ByteArrayOutputStream to byte array first, than use the above method.

Answer (score 1):

Can use use Integer.toHexString()? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toHexString(int)

Comment: and in my actual case ? i'm trying to figure out because i never did this ... thank you