# Perl's pack function equivalent in Java

Tags: java, perl, hex, pack

I have some Perl code that I need to transpose in Java. In this code I have to deal with Perl's [`pack`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pack.html). Is there an equivalent function in Java? The Perl code looks something like this:

```
$somevar = pack "H*", $vartopack;
```

Comment: Look at the answers for this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/923863/converting-a-string-to-hexadecimal-in-java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perl's `pack` / `unpack` functions are a highly versatile conversion utility with its own [format syntax](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pack.html) (used in `H*` here, which makes it take an arbitrarily long hex string as input) of which there is no direct equivalent in the Java world. However, to translate...

```
$somevar = pack "H*", $vartoconvert;
```

...to Java, you can for example use:

```
byte[] somevar = javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary(vartoconvert);
```

For more information read the [`DatatypeConverter` class reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter.html) from Javadocs.

Answer (score 1):

```
String hex = "4a616d6573";
StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < hex.length(); i+=2) {
    String str = hex.substring(i, i+2);
    output.append((char)Integer.parseInt(str, 16));
}
System.out.println(output);
```