# JAVA String to char

Tags: java, string, char

I have a String representing the hex value of a char, such as: "0x6d4b". How can I get the character it represents as a char?

```
String c = "0x6d4b";
char m = ???
```

Comment: Try to take a look to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/923863/converting-a-string-to-hexadecimal-in-java

Answer (score 9):

```
// Drop "0x" in order to parse
String c = "6d4b";
// Parse hexadecimal integer
int i = Integer.parseInt( c, 16 );
// Note that this method returns char[]
char[] cs = Character.toChars( i );
// Prints 测
System.out.println( cs );
```

Comment: are you sure it's not just ``(char)i``?

Comment: Yes, if the resulting value is used as a `char`, the results are the same. The method call gives you the added bonus of readily available javadoc that tells what you're actually getting.

Answer (score 2):

```
String s = "6d4b";
int i = Integer.parseInt( s, 16 );   // to convert hex to integer
char ca= (char) i;
System.out.println(ca);
```

Comment: all in one line version: `System.out.println ( (char)Integer.parseInt(c.substring(2), 16) );`

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.println((char)Integer.parseInt("6d4b",16));
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this,

```
String s ="0x6d4b" ;
        char[] c = s.toCharArray();

        for (char cc : c){

            System.out.print(cc);
        }
```

Comment: have you tested it before posting because its not working. and by the way its not what is asked. So -1

Comment: @MohammadAdil It works on my side (compilation wise) but you're right, it's not what's wanted