# How to Convert string to HexaDecimal?

Tags: android, string, hex, type-conversion

I have a string like this:

```
"12"
```

And I need to convert it to a hex value like this:

```
0x12
```

I have a byte array like this

```
// 00 20 22 80 08 24 pi nn ff ff ff ff ff 
byte VerifyingAPDU[] = { (byte)0x00,(byte)0x20,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x80,(byte)0x08,(byte)0x24,
                     (byte)0x12,(byte)0x34, //pi nn
                     (byte)0xff, (byte)0xff, (byte)0xff, (byte)0xff, (byte)0xff };
Now i want to replace pi nn with user entered value in Eidter (EditText). how to do this ?
```

For example user entered 1111 in editer i have to replace Ox12 --> 0x11 and 0x34-->0x11.

Comment: This question is answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/923863/converting-a-string-to-hexadecimal-in-java

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This should be

```
Integer.toHexString(Integer.parseInt(String));
```

Ref : [Convert to/from hexadecimal](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/conversion/decimal_hexadecimal.shtml)

Comment: I tried like that.. see if i have String a = "12"; i want to get create hex value for that is `0x12`. how to do this.

Comment: @RajaReddyPolamReddy, er, `"0x" + Integer.toHexString(Integer.parseInt(String));`

Comment: I agreed with @Simon. You can do like that. Is there any problem

Comment: @PankajKumar i will check like this, let u know the result.

Comment: Its giving me the HexaDecimal Value upto that it's ok. for my requirement i want to do like this. look at the edited Question.

Comment: @RajaReddyPolamReddy ahhhh your updated question is completely different from asked.. And you unaccepted the answer... :)

Comment: Sry for that. Please can u tell me the solution for this. i am struck at that.please...

Comment: For converting String to Hex this code working well..

Comment: `int inputInteger = Integer.valueOf(edit_text_value); 
  
  String firstHex = "0x" + Integer.toHexString(inputInteger/ 100);
  String secondHex = "0x" + Integer.toHexString(inputInteger % 100);` Use these codes.. here I assumed that length of edittext is set to 4.

Comment: Actually, if i enter 1234 was the pin i have to get 0x12 and 0x34, but this code gives me like this 0xc and 0x22..

Comment: yes I am right till you are asking about HEX. But again you are saying another thing if 12 should be 0X12 then this is not a HEX of 12. You can simply add '0X' to given string..

Comment: @PankajKumar i tried to convert String to byte, i am unable to convert it. can u help me on this typecast..please.