# How can convert a hexdecimal IP string into IP4 dotted string...

Tags: java

I want to convert a hexadecimal string into IP4 string , I googled but didn't get any good way. Could anybody suggest me a simple way. 
Thanks .

Comment: Use [Integer.parseInt(hex, 16)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) on two hex characters each.

Answer (score 3):

Please try this method.

```
String hexValue = "Hex IP";
String ip = "";

for(int i = 0; i < hexValue.length(); i = i + 2) {
   ip = ip + Integer.valueOf(hexValue.subString(i, i+2), 16) + ".";
}

System.out.println("Ip = " + ip);
```

Answer (score 0):

In this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/923863/converting-a-string-to-hexadecimal-in-java) the author gave a method for printing out an int into hexadecimal.