# How to extract URL to video from Website Code

Tags: java, video, encryption, stream

I am in the process of making an application that streams anime from sites. However in order to do so, I need the direct link to a video for instance:

http://s1000.animepremium.tv/stream/74017.mp4

However, this site I'm currently trying to stream from animeseason.com, but I cannot find the link to the video from the code.

Here's the code:

`<a href="#" onclick="show_player('player1', '%{3c%-69%$66%X72%!61%F6d%N65%Z20%@6d%[61%W72%J67%@69%U6e%@68%C65%J69%V67%R68%B74%D3d%-22%[30%G22%S20%P6d%A61%M72%~67%Y69%A6e%T77%V69%*64%D74%I68%+3d%R22%[30%Z22%L20%Q73%]63%A72%+6f%X6c%C6c%G69%F6e%U67%H3d%I22%Q6e%C6f%P22%[20%S66%P72%G61%F6d%A65%H62%Y6f%V72%?64%!65%#72%+3d%E22%Y30%X22%Q20%A77%T69%Q64%+74%C68%T3d%D22%H35%?34%L30%Q22%P20%O68%*65%K69%{67%H68%R74%+3d%H22%Z33%W30%@34%Y22%K20%S73%W72%P63%C3d%F22%*68%D74%Y74%H70%A3a%!2f%~2f%E6d%]70%~34%P75%L70%B6c%#6f%D61%M64%W2e%K63%#6f%U6d%R2f%O65%C6d%G62%?65%M64%Z2d%W34%!6b%@68%!71%T66%*7a%M37%~34%{6e%?67%N6a%-6e%[2e%A68%L74%G6d%B6c%B22%J3e%O3c%Y2f%T69%D66%E72%+61%S6d%H65%E3e');return false">Mp4up Player</a>`

As you can see the video seems to be encrypted, is it possible to decrypt? If so how would I achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Edit: I already have a streaming thing set up in java that will work for any video such as the one from the first link. I just need to know how to decrypt the video link from the code above...

Edit2; I am using Java, so if there is already a solution in java please tell me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Challenge accepted if you mean the video URL is encrypted and not the video itself.
And it is not like the video URL is encrypted, it is more like "obfuscated" since the structure of the data is visible. So to de-obfuscate:

```
public class Q21300109 {

public static final String urlEncoded = "%{3c%-69%$66%X72%!61%F6d%N65%Z20%@6d%[61%W72%J67%@69%U6e%@68%C65%J69%V67%R68%B74%D3d%-22%[30%G22%S20%P6d%A61%M72%~67%Y69%A6e%T77%V69%*64%D74%I68%+3d%R22%[30%Z22%L20%Q73%]63%A72%+6f%X6c%C6c%G69%F6e%U67%H3d%I22%Q6e%C6f%P22%[20%S66%P72%G61%F6d%A65%H62%Y6f%V72%?64%!65%#72%+3d%E22%Y30%X22%Q20%A77%T69%Q64%+74%C68%T3d%D22%H35%?34%L30%Q22%P20%O68%*65%K69%{67%H68%R74%+3d%H22%Z33%W30%@34%Y22%K20%S73%W72%P63%C3d%F22%*68%D74%Y74%H70%A3a%!2f%~2f%E6d%]70%~34%P75%L70%B6c%#6f%D61%M64%W2e%K63%#6f%U6d%R2f%O65%C6d%G62%?65%M64%Z2d%W34%!6b%@68%!71%T66%*7a%M37%~34%{6e%?67%N6a%-6e%[2e%A68%L74%G6d%B6c%B22%J3e%O3c%Y2f%T69%D66%E72%+61%S6d%H65%E3e";

public static void main(String... args) {

    String senc = urlEncoded;
    int offSet = senc.indexOf('%');
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    while (offSet > -1) {
        String hex = senc.substring(offSet + 2, offSet + 4);
        // hex to char, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/10101779/3080094
        char c = (char)Integer.parseInt(hex, 16);
        sb.append(c);
        offSet = senc.indexOf('%', offSet + 1);
    }
    System.out.println(sb.toString());
}
}
```

Which produces:

```
<iframe marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" scrolling="no" 
frameborder="0" width="540" height="304" 
src="http://mp4upload.com/embed-4khqfz74ngjn.html"></iframe>
```

Comment: Thanks that's exactly what I was looking for. What does obfuscated mean?

Comment: [Obfuscation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obfuscation) (or beclouding) is the hiding of intended meaning in communication, making communication confusing, wilfully ambiguous, and harder to interpret