# Printing the address of hex string instead of hex string value

Tags: java, string, forms, printing, hex

I converted a byte array into string by doing

```
String s = encryptedBytes1.toString();
String gh = convertStringToHex(s);
```

Then I printed on screen `gh` which is the hex form it returned this:

```
gh:[B@5985910
```

this is the function convert

```
public static String convertStringToHex(String str){
    char[] chars = str.toCharArray();
    StringBuffer hex = new StringBuffer();
    for(int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++){
        hex.append(Integer.toHexString((int)chars[i]));
    }
    return hex.toString();
}
```

Can any one help me printing the hex form string?

Comment: What does convertStringToHex(String s) return?

Comment: The variable gh is a ByteArray. You can see this from the default to String: [B@....

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9655181/convert-from-byte-array-to-hex-string-in-java

Answer (score 2):

In general you can convert string and hex values (numbers) with the following functions:

```
String hexString1 = "0x20";
Integer integer = Integer.decode(hexString); // is 32
String hexString1 = String.toHexString(integer); // is "20"
```

Now you need to iterate over your byteArray/String.

EDIT: As you specified your question, please see this answer on SO. I guess it is the same problem: [Converting A String To Hexadecimal In Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/923863/converting-a-string-to-hexadecimal-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

**encryptedBytes1.toString()** is giving you a string representation of the [object](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29) because all arrays are objects in Java it is not converting a byte array into a String.

I think that you are not converting your byte array to String properly. This works for me.

```
    byte encryptedBytes1[] = "ABCDEFGHIK".getBytes();
    String aux = new String(encryptedBytes1);
    System.out.println(convertStringToHex(aux));
```

41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 4b

- Keep in mind that you may need to specify a charset and that the [primitive](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) data byte takes 1 byte and char(which is meant to contain a Unicode Character) takes 2.