# Java String comparison

Tags: java, string, equals

I have the following statement in my java code

```
System.out.println(cName+" "+pName+" "+cName.equals(pName));
```

Output is

```
???????????????? ???????????????? false
```

The equals should return true right as the two strings have equal number of '?'. But I a m getting false

Comment: what is your platform encoding? Try to convert string to hex and compare hex representations http://stackoverflow.com/questions/923863/converting-a-string-to-hexadecimal-in-java

Comment: As @popalka points out, `?` is often substituted for a character which cannot be displayed.  It is not necessarily the character `?`.

Comment: The String consists of `?` symbols.

Comment: Did you manually declare the String to equal "????????????????" ?

Comment: where are cName and pName defined? What version of Java/ what OS are you running? If define the variables it does output true for me ...
String a = "????????????????";
String b = "????????????????";

System.out.println(a+"   "+b+" "+a.equals(b));

Comment: It reads from a XML file. The XML attribute has Question marks.
<cName>????????????????</cName>
<pName>????????????????</pName>

Comment: Based on this, you could have more special characters in there that don't display (refer to @icza answer below). Open your XML file in a hex editor if you wish.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Those 2 `String`s might be equal in their *"printed"* form on your console, but their content is certainly not equal as proved by the return value of the `String.equals()`.

They most likely contain characters which your console cannot display, therefore your console displays `'?'` characters for the "undisplayable" characters.

Another possibility could be they contain characters which when printed on the console have no visual appearance. Such characters may be the zero character (`'\0'`) and control characters (whose code is less than 32) but this depends on the console how and what it displays.

**Note:** Even if you open the file where these `String`s are stored or initialized and you see the same question marks, it is still possible that your editor is also not able to display the characters and the editor also displays question marks (`'?'`) for undisplayable characters or for the characters with no visual appearance.

**How to show the difference?**

Iterate over the characters of the strings, and print them as `int` numbers where you will see the difference:

```
String s = "Test";
for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
    System.out.println((int) s.charAt(i));
```

Now if you see the same numbers printed, then yes, you can be sure they are the same, but then `String.equals()` would return `true`.

Comment: The string consists of `?` symbols. No special characters.

Comment: Added another possibility: special characters with no visual appearance (depends on the console).

Comment: Zero-width joiner and zero-width non-joiner, for instance.

Answer (score 0):

Might be because of whitespace it is coming `false`

check for this :

```
System.out.println(cName+" "+pName+" "+(cName.trim()).equals(pName.trim()));
```

Comment: @NicePixel because I tried same thing and I am getting true