# receiving the data as hexadezimal on the server?

Tags: java, sockets

I am currently sending a String to the server and I am getting ASCCII characters when iterating through the buffer on the server side. How can I send the String to receive it as hexadezimal on the server?

**code**

```
String message;
String result;
String aString = "#2016011400000060.00#010104#004500##";
// String aString = "###";
BufferedReader inFromUser = new BufferedReader(new StringReader(aString));

Socket clientSocket = new Socket("localhost", 1000);
DataOutputStream outToServer = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
BufferedReader inFromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
message = inFromUser.readLine();
outToServer.writeBytes(message + '\n');
result = inFromServer.readLine();
System.out.println(result);
clientSocket.close();
```

Comment: You are getting what you sent. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: How are you reading it on the server? Why does it expect hexadecimal on a raw socket instead of plain bytes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible duplicate:

[Converting A String To Hexadecimal In Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/923863/converting-a-string-to-hexadecimal-in-java)

```
public String toHex(String arg) {
    return String.format("%040x", new BigInteger(1, arg.getBytes(/*YOUR_CHARSET?*/)));
}
```

Comment: but how can I send it with the socket since there is no writeHexa() method?

Comment: @TheBook Call `writeBytes(toHex(message + '\n'));`

Comment: @TheBook That is because there is no HEX data type in Java. Is unclear what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thanks sir for your answer. but is not the parameter arg is my message? what do you mean with `YOUR_CHARSET`?

Comment: @TheBook You can specify the charset via the [`StandardCharsets`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/StandardCharsets.html) class. For example you can give StandardCharsets.UTF_8 as the parameter.