# Jaunt Java getText() returning correct text but with lots of "?"

Tags: java, jaunt-api

The title explains all, also, I have tried removing them

(because the text is there, but instead of "aldo" there is "al?do", also it seems to have a random pattern)

with `(String).replace("?", "")`, but with no success.

I have also used this, with a combination of UTF_8,UTF_16 and ISO-8859, with no success.

```
byte[] ptext = tempName.getBytes(UTF_8); 
String tempName1 = new String(ptext, UTF_16);
```

An example of what I am getting:

```
Studded Regular Sweatshirt          // Instead of this
S?tudde?d R?eg?ular? Sw?eats?h?irt  // I get this
```

Could it be the website that notices the headless browser and tries to "spoof" its content? How can I overcome this?

Comment: Looks like an encoding problem. Don't just delete those characters, fix the encoding issue.

Comment: @tadman I used a command on chrome to check which encoding the website uses, but it is the default one with jaunt. Also, replacing the "?" does NOT work.

Comment: @JaneS. that's because you might see it as `?`, but that might just be a default character which is displayed when the actual character cannot be displayed. So when you do your replacing, you are not actually targetting the problem. Listen to what @tadman said and fix the encoding issue

Comment: You'll want to inspect `tempName` more closely to see what bytes are involved there. If it's not 7-bit ASCII you'll have to dig deeper and find out where those extra bytes are coming from.

Comment: @tadman yeah I figured that much but how can I inspect a string?

Comment: Post it in HEX form and let me see use charset ISO8859_1 by link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/923863/converting-a-string-to-hexadecimal-in-java

Comment: @YuJiaao what charset do I need to use in method `toHex`?

Comment: try use ISO8859_1 @JaneS.

Comment: @YuJiaao Alright, here it is `5363613f3f3f7266613f3f3f63653f3f3f20453f3f3f6d62723f3f3f6f69643f3f3f65726564204c653f3f3f6174686572204a613f3f3f636b6574`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks very likely that site you scrapping intent mix up the `3f` and `64` characters into your result.
so you have to mask your self as a normal browser to scrapping or filter it out by replacing.

text simple

```
Sca???rfa???ce??? E???mbr???oi�d???ered L�e???athe
```

after filteration

```
Scarface Embroidered Leather




//Sca???rfa???ce??? E???mbr???oi�d???ered L�e???athe
//Scarface Embroidered Leathe

String hex="5363613f3f3f7266613f3f3f63653f3f3f20453f3f3f6d62723f3f3f6f69‌​643f3f3f65726564204c‌​653f3f3f61746865";
byte[] bytes= hexStringToBytes(hex);

//the only line you need
String res = new String(bytes,"UTF-8").replaceAll("\\\u003f","").replaceAll('�',"").replaceAll("�","");

private static byte charToByte(char c) {
    return (byte) "0123456789ABCDEF".indexOf(new String(c));
}


public static byte[] hexStringToBytes(String hexString) {
    if (hexString == null || hexString.equals("")) {
        return null;
    }
    hexString = hexString.toUpperCase();
    int length = hexString.length() / 2;
    char[] hexChars = hexString.toCharArray();
    byte[] d = new byte[length];
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        int pos = i * 2;
        d[i] = (byte) (charToByte(hexChars[pos]) << 4 | charToByte(hexChars[pos + 1]));

    }
    return d;
}

public static String bytesToHexString(byte[] src){
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder("");
    if (src == null || src.length <= 0) {
        return null;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < src.length; i++) {
        int v = src[i] & 0xFF;
        String hv = Integer.toHexString(v);
        if (hv.length() < 2) {
            stringBuilder.append(0);
        }
        stringBuilder.append(hv);
    }
    return stringBuilder.toString();
}

public   String printHexString( byte[] b) {
    String a = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) { 
        String hex = Integer.toHexString(b[i] & 0xFF); 
        if (hex.length() == 1) { 
            hex = '0' + hex; 
        }

        a = a+hex;
    } 

    return a;
}
```

Comment: If anyone is having problems with `charToByte`, just use `String.valueOf(c)` instead of `new String(c)`.