# Convert String to Hex in Java

Tags: java, crc16

I want using CRC16, but first, i want to convert string to hex. because integer must be 16 bytes. i still confused to encrypt using CRC16. this is my code.

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
            String input = "skn";
            byte[] valuesDefault = input.getBytes();
            System.out.println("input:" + input);
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(valuesDefault));
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting A String To Hexadecimal In Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/923863/converting-a-string-to-hexadecimal-in-java)

Comment: @Shashwat no, the answer to that question is horrible, regardless of the upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this below

```
DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(input.getBytes())
```