# How to format a String/char to it's hex value correct

Tags: java, string, formatting, hex

I am trying to convert a String to it's hex representation. I have the following (test) input
`�¾��Hello World!`

The correct hex representation should be: 
`00 BE 00 00 48 65 6C 6C 6F 20 57 6F 72 6C 64 21`

I am trying to format the String with 
`String.format("%x", new BigInteger(toConvert.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"))).split("(?<=\\G.{2})");`

But this format operation ignores the first character (if it is a hex-null) and leads to `BE 00 00 48 65 6C 6C 6F 20 57 6F 72 6C 64 21`

I have already played around a little bit with the parts around the `"%x"` but nothing helped.

But I am sure, that you can help me :)

Comment: Java’s String class is fundamentally not binary safe; any operations on non-printable bytes (like `00`) cannot be expected to work.

Comment: Look at this https://stackoverflow.com/a/36972153/2139631

Answer (score 0):

To format with leading zeroes, specify the *width* of the formatted hex value, and request leading zeroes.

E.g. if result is 6 bytes, instead of format `"%x"`, use format `"%012x"`.

For your code, do this: `"%0" + toConvert.length() * 2 + "x"`