# How to format string in hex in Java?

Tags: java, string, hex

I want to format string in hex in Java.

e.g. input: `123123`, output: `1E 0F 03`

Here is my code:

```
String.format("%02X", integer)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting A String To Hexadecimal In Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/923863/converting-a-string-to-hexadecimal-in-java)

Comment: Are you sure you want `1E 0F 03` and not `01 E0 F3`?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
        int n = 123123;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String sep = "";
        while (n > 0) {
            int nybble = n & 0xFF;
            sb.insert(0, sep);
            sb.insert(0, String.format("%02X", nybble));
            sep = " ";
            n >>>= 8;
        }
        System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

Comment: Did you know that you can append StringBuilder calls?  So you can do `sb.insert(0, sep).insert(0, String.format("%02X", nybble));`

Comment: > Did you know that you can append StringBuilder calls?<
You mean *chain* calls. Yes, I did but I thought the code might be a bit clearer for not doing that in this particular case.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this

- convert the value to uppercase hex
- prepend a "0" based on length
- then split and rejoin (the regex splits on the zero width area after every two characters).

```
for (int val : new int[] { 123123, 122, 94392, 9200812 }) {
    String valStr = String.format("%X",val);
    valStr = (valStr.length() % 2 == 0 ? "" : "0") + valStr;
    String result = String.join(" ", valStr.split("(?<=\\G(..))"));
    System.out.printf("%7d = %10s = %s%n", val, valStr, result);
}
```

Prints

```
 123123 =     01E0F3 = 01 E0 F3
    122 =         7A = 7A
  94392 =     0170B8 = 01 70 B8
9200812 =     8C64AC = 8C 64 AC
```